# Suggestions on Ruby code for API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i was acually trying to write Ruby code for the api blogs

i have written the ruby code as

```
  Loading development environment (Rails 2.3.8)
  >> class Blogpost < ActiveRecord::Base
  >> has_many :taggings
  >> has_many :tags,:through => :taggings
  >> end
  => nil
 >> class Taggings < ActiveRecord::Base
 >> belongs_to :blogpost
>> belongs_to :tag
>> end
=> nil



?> @tags=Tag.find_by_name("blog7")
=> #<Tag id: 4, name: "blog7">
>> @taggings=Tagging.find_by_id(@tags.id)
=> #<Tagging id: 4, tag_id: 1, taggable_id: 4, taggable_type: "Blogpost",    created_at: "2010-09-02 10:03:08">
>> @blogposts=Blogpost.find_by_id(@taggings.taggable_id)
  => #<Blogpost id: 4, title: "blog post4", type: nil, slug: "blog-post4", description: "<p>BLOG desc 4</p>", meta: nil, user_id: 1, category_id: 379344121, times_viewed: 2, comments_count: 0, published: 1, created_at: "2010-09-02 10:03:08", updated_at: "2010-09-03 05:11:46", delta: false>
```

Whether this way of writing Ruby code is the correct procedure for API..

Please give suggestions ..

Comment: Should 'class Taggings' be 'class Tagging'?

Comment: ya it should be Tagging only.. My table name is taggings

Comment: Is the code above is the rite one to  be used???

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean in the context of the API. If you mean, is this the right way to define an ActiveRecord class, then yes, you did. If you mean, is this the best way to find objects with the find api, my only suggestion would be that it will default to id, so `find_by_id` is redundant `Tagging.find @tag.id` would work, and generally when doing a lookup from a controller it will be more likely to find it by the params `Tagging.find params[:id]`